# MasterPage References and Inheirits

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

I have multiple Master Pages arranged in a folder of my project that have the following path 
MyProject / MasterPagesFolder / Site.Master

And the pages of my project using the Site.Master have this path: 
MyProject / PagesFolder / ClientFolder / ClientPage.aspx

With this structure, the page does not load css style Site.Master but if the path of Teste.aspx page is changed to: 
MyProject / PagesFolder / ClientFolder / ClientPage.aspx 
the style of my MasterPage will work properly. 
  Why does this occur?

## My MasterPage Initial Code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Cliente.master.cs" Inherits="AcertSite.MasterPages.Cliente" %>
```

## My WebPage Initial Code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Cliente.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Teste.aspx.cs" Inherits="AcertSite.Paginas.Cliente.Teste" %>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is not so clear. For example, you said " I remove my page and leave the folder with the path `MyProject / Pages / Client / ClientPage.aspx`" but this path point to a file not a folder !

Comment: The Master Page is not displayed properly with the Teste.aspx page when the site Teste.aspx page is defined as: 
MyProject / PagesFolder / ClientFolder / Teste.aspx 

If the location of Teste.aspx page is changed to: 
MyProject / PagesFolder / Teste.aspx 
entire structure and design of the Master Page will be loaded correctly.

Comment: What I find strange, is that in your question you are talking about `MyProject / MasterPagesFolder / Site.Master` but in your example there is  `"~/MasterPages/Cliente.Master"` ! What's the exact name and location of your masterpage ?

Comment: Sorry. This is exact location:

Master Page:
AcertSite/MasterPages/Cliente.Master

Web Page:
AcertSite/Paginas/Cliente/Teste.aspx

Comment: I edited my question. See above to insert an image with the file structure of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like explained in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx the "~/" is a relative path to the Web Application in IIS.
If you are using IIS define the AcertSite folder as a Web Application (Contextual menu\convert to web application).